# Android OSM: How to replace default current location overlay icon

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using android *osmdroid* map library, is it possible to modify default current location overlay icon (person icon) with compass icon?

Comment: Please consider extracting your answer into an "answer post".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and to improve my answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer:**

I achieved this by customizing the OSM map library in which I created `MyCustomLocationOverlay` class extending `MyLocationOverlay` and override

```
draw(Canvas c, MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {
    //do your code here
}
```

method and draw compass on canvas.